# Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'OrgID' to data type int

Tags: c#, sql, stored-procedures, visual-studio-2015, ssms

So I'm teaching myself how to do stored procedures in SQL Server Management Studio, and I am attempting to make one to replace a string query I had in my C# code in Visual Studio. My original bit of code that I had was

```
 InsertQuery = "INSERT INTO License (OrgID, LicensingKey) VALUES (@OrgID, @LicensingKey)"; // Query to insert into the database table.
 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(InsertQuery, con);
 cmd.Parameters.Add("@LicensingKey", SqlDbType.Int).Value = LicensingKey;  
 cmd.Parameters.Add("@OrgID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = OrgID;
 cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Where OrgID and LicensingKey are two ints passed by the method this code is in.

My stored procedure that I made in my database is this:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[LicenseInsert]
@OrgID int = OrgID,
@LicensingKey int = LicensingKey

AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
INSERT INTO License (OrgID, LicensingKey) 
VALUES (@OrgID, @LicensingKey)
END
```

And now that same bit of code I had I replaced with this:

```
InsertQuery = "EXEC LicenseInsert "; // Query to insert into the database table.
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(InsertQuery, con);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

BUT this gives me the error of "Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'OrgID' to data type int", and it's saying that

```
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

is the culprit.

Can someone walk me through what I am doing wrong? 
Thank you kindly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would expect that you'd get some sort of error that a parameter is missing, but to execute a stored procedure you need to use just the stored procedure name and change the command type to `StoredProcedure`:

```
InsertQuery = "LicenseInsert"; // Query to insert into the database table.
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(InsertQuery, con);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;  // <------------

cmd.Parameters.Add("@LicensingKey", SqlDbType.Int).Value = LicensingKey;  
cmd.Parameters.Add("@OrgID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = OrgID;

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Also I think your stored procedure definition is invalid.  it should be:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[LicenseInsert]
@OrgID int,
@LicensingKey int
```

Comment: Ahhhhh so the CommandType was what was throwing me off! You're also right about the stored procedure definition being invalid, I wasn't sure if what I was doing was valid and so now I know. Thank you so much! The learning adventure continues haha!